# ASP.NET MVC C# Google Drive API Redirect mismatch URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

For reference, I followed this site https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-drive-api-in-aspnet/236 on how to upload a file to Google Drive in a Web Application.

This is my code to get the DriveService

```cs
public static string[] Scopes = { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive };

public static DriveService GetService()
{
    //get Credentials from client_secret.json file 
    UserCredential credential;
    DriveService service = null;

    //Root Folder of project
    var CSPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(CSPath, "client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            String FolderPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
            String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "DriveServiceCredentials.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;
        }
        //create Drive API service.
        service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveMVCUpload",
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException);

    }
    return service;
            
}
```

The problem occurs at getting the credential from GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync. When that line runs, I would be redirected to
[this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSQSq.png) (The port of the redirect URI http://127.0.0.1:52829/authorize/ changes everytime I run this code).

I have looked into Google's Error docs and other stack overflow explaining that I must add the redirect URI on the console in which I did [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOkxD.png) but it still has the redirect_uri_mismatch error. When I do just open the redirect URI (example : http://127.0.0.1:52829/authorize/) given in the error, I get the following

[image]

. But then an exception would be thrown

```
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at .........
One or more errors occurred.
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"", Description:"", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
**service** was null.
```

and I couldn't find much about this specific exception error :

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"", Description:"", Uri:"" but I believe this is because of the redirect mismatch URI problem.

For more information: The current link of the web application is http://localhost:61506 and the link when I run the code above is at http://localhost:61506/AutoFileTransfer/Index

So I don't really know why I get this redirect mismatch URI error nor do I know how to solve the
`Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"", Description:"", Uri:""` problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem you are having is that you are using  `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` which is designed to work with installed applications only its not going to work with Asp .net

For asp .net MVC you should be doing the following

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

The official sample can be found [web-applications-asp.net-mvc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)

The second issue you have is that your IDE is changing the ports on you. You need to fix it so that it uses a static port then you can add your redirect uri properly.   [How to create Google Oauth2 web application credentials in 2021.](https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU)  [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

As for that example you are following the author may have gotten it to work on local host but it will never work hosted as a website as GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync will open the browser window on the machine that its running on.  This being a web server will never work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and swift reply. I was able to get it working!

Comment: @WilliamTjandra how did you get it working? I too followed that tutorial and have not been able to get my uploader working. I was supposed to get this project done in a few hours and mistakenly thought that tutorial was easy enough. :/

Comment: @Jamie open a new question with your code i would be happy to take a look

Comment: @DaImTo thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944104/mvc-web-app-to-upload-files-with-google-drive-api-uri-mismatch